# Not able to push to GitHub

Tags: github

I am trying to push code to my private repo on github but I am getting the error in the screenshot.

I made a new branch and tried to push but for some reason it is not working.

[image: The screenshot that has the error]

Comment: In general, please include error messages like this as code blocks, not as images.  Images aren't searchable or accessible, and they prevent others from finding this question to either answer or find an answer.  Additionally, if you search for that error message, you'll find a bunch of similar questions, which will probably help out.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error message it states "This exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00MB"

So you've to exclude that file from being pushed.
I would recommend [this .gitignore file](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Android.gitignore) which will prevent this file and other files from being pushed.

In order to use the `.gitignore` file, create in the root directory of your repository (The same folder .git is in) a file called `.gitignore` paste the content of the site above in that file.

Comment: Okkk.....I actually got that......But I am not sure what to add in gitignore file.....Can you help me with that?

Comment: @SpideyVerse I changed the answer a little bit to explain how to use the gitignore file

Comment: thanks......I will try it out.....So basically I have to paste ```android/app/build`` or the entire address?

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the error - you are trying to push a 176MB file, which is greater than GitHub supports. I'd suggest putting it into your .gitignore or using [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/).